# Problems with JAXB XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, list, xml-parsing, jaxb

I’m working on a project in which I will use JAXB to parse an XML file containing the following weather station information: Name, station ID, latitude/longitude, and url. Right now I intend to test everything by printing a weather station by name only. I have debugged my code but when I try to run: I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"wx_station_index"). Expected elements are (none)

Does anyone have an explanation? Any help would be appreciated. My code and sample of XML are posted below:

```
//create criteria for weather station info
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StationTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */

@XmlElement(name = "station_id")
String station_id;

@XmlElement(name = "state")
String state;

@XmlElement(name = "station_name")
String stationName;

@XmlElement(name = "latitude")
double latitude;

@XmlElement(name = "longitude")
double longitude;

@XmlElement(name = "html_url")
String htmlUrl;

public String getStationID(){
    return station_id;
}

public void setStationId(String station_id)
{
     this.station_id = station_id;
}

public String getState(){
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state)
{
     this.state = state;
}

public String getStationName(){
    return stationName;
}

public void setStationName(String station_name)
{
     this.stationName = stationName;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude)
{
     this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude)
{
     this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getUrl(){
    return htmlUrl;
}

public void setUrl(String url){
    this.htmlUrl = htmlUrl;

}
```

}
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

//create list for all weather stations

@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso(value = StationTest.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StationListTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
@XmlElement(name = "station")
private ArrayList<StationTest> stationList;

public void setStationListTest(ArrayList<StationTest> StationList){
    this.stationList = StationList;
}

public ArrayList<StationTest> getStationListTest(){
    return stationList;
}

}

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

//final Test of JAXB
public class Test3 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
//read xml
private static final String STATION_XML = "src/flwxindex3.xml";

//main method
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {

    //create list object
    ArrayList<StationTest> StationList = new ArrayList<StationTest>();

    final JAXBContext jaxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(StationListTest.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbc.createUnmarshaller();

    //create list for iteration, then iterate printing by name only
    StationListTest stationListTest = (StationListTest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(STATION_XML));
    ArrayList<StationTest> list = stationListTest.getStationListTest();
    //final StationListTest stations = (StationListTest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("src/flwxindex3.xml"));
    for (final StationTest station : list) {
        System.out.println(station.getStationName());
    }
}
```

}

The actual xml as requested (Thought I included it, sorry):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wx_station_index>
    <credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
    <credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
    <image>
            <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
            <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
            <link>http://weather.gov</link>
    </image>
    <suggested_pickup>08:00 EST</suggested_pickup>
    <suggested_pickup_period>1140</suggested_pickup_period>

<station>
    <station_id>NFNA</station_id>
    <state>FJ</state>
    <station_name>Nausori</station_name>
    <latitude>-18.05</latitude>
    <longitude>178.567</longitude>
    <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html</html_url>
    <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.rss</rss_url>
    <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
    <station_id>KCEW</station_id>
    <state>FL</state>
            <station_name>Crestview, Sikes Airport</station_name>
    <latitude>30.79</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.52</longitude>
            <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KCEW.html</html_url>
            <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.rss</rss_url>
            <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

Comment: can you provide the actual xml please.

Comment: not sure if it's a copy paste error or intented by design, but <wx_station_index> is not closed. If it's by design, this would mean that we expect a wx_station_index element in which we expect to find station elements. In your java code, we are handling a list of stations (which would be correct if you only had station elements in there)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that wx_station_index is not a typo.

I've added some annotations to instruct jaxb on what part of the xml to map on what part of your code. Changing your StationListTest to the following should work a whole lot better.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//create list for all weather stations
@XmlRootElement(name="wx_station_index")
public class StationListTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
@XmlElement(name="station")    
private ArrayList<StationTest> StationList;

public StationListTest(){
    StationList=new ArrayList<StationTest>();
}

public void setStationListTest(ArrayList<StationTest> StationList){
    this.StationList = StationList;
}

public ArrayList<StationTest> getStationListTest(){
    return StationList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the named property `StationList` on your class `StationListTest` and the implicit `station` list attribute in the XML document. This needs to be resolved by explicitly defining what elements of your XML the `StationList` property be populated from:

```
@XmlElement(name = "station")
private ArrayList<StationTest> StationList;
```

Some other quick notes:

- You should follow Java naming patterns (camel case) for class and variable names. So `StationList` should be `stationList`, for example).
- As a general rule you should annotate all your top level data classes with `@XMLRootElement`.
- As a general rule, you should use the most generic form of a type when defining your Java class (`List`, instead of `ArrayList`).
- You should indicate which other classes are involved in your mapping with an `@XmlSeeAlso`

The following class definitions work with your XML:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "station")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StationTest {

    @XmlElement(name = "station_id")
    String stationId;

    String state;

    @XmlElement(name = "station_name")
    String stationName;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    @XmlElement(name = "html_url")
    String htmlUrl;

    // Constructor, getters, setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "wx_station_index")
@XmlSeeAlso(value = StationTest.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StationListTest {
    @XmlElement(name = "station")
    private List<StationTest> stationList;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one issue: For '@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)' - I get an error that XMLAccessType cannot be resolved as a variable. If I comment out and try to run my whole program my error is this:Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"wx_station_index"). Expected elements are <{}stationListTest>,<{}stationTest>

Comment: You need to import `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType`. If you are using Eclipse you can just hit Ctrl-Shift-o (or Command-Shift-o on Mac) to organize imports. Other IDE's have similar functionality.

Comment: Ok. Done. But I still get the error: Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"wx_station_index"). Expected elements are <{}stationListTest>,<{}stationTest> -Thanks all the same.

Comment: @dave - are you sure you didn't specify a `name` attribute on any of your `@XmlRootElement`s?

Comment: I followed the example above but the error seems produced by something pertaining to <{}stationListTest>,<{}stationTest> and I don't know why.

Comment: Try explicitly naming the Java entities as I've shown in my edited answer.

Comment: I just renamed following your example. Still getting the same error. I've reposted my code in accordance with your recommendations. Anymore insight?

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept whatever answer helped you the most. Good luck with the rest of the project.